# Reach main urls.py and use another app url

Tags: django

I have use 2 apps in my project named post and gallery. In url localhost:8000/en, I am using post.urls specifically "homepage". In homepage, when I want go to `{% url "gallery:gallery_detail" "photos" %}` it gives me an error. Because even though it takes a keyword "photos" it can not find any pattern specifically "gallery_detail".

My question is how can I reach this anathor app's url ?

My main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^ckeditor/', include("ckeditor_uploader.urls")),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(


url(r'^gallery/', include("gallery.urls",namespace="gallery")),
url(r'^', include("post.urls", namespace="post")),
)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My post.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from post.views import HomePageDetailView, AboutDetailView, \
    CategoryDetailView, SponsorshipDetailView, CommonDetailView, NewsEntryDetailView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomePageDetailView.as_view(), name="homepage"),
    url(r'^about/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', AboutDetailView.as_view(),
        name="about_detail"),
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view(),
        name="category_detail"),
    url(r'^sponsorship/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', SponsorshipDetailView.as_view(),
        name="sponsorship_detail"),

    url(r'^news/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', NewsEntryDetailView.as_view(),
        name="news_detail"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', CommonDetailView.as_view(),
        name="common_detail"),
]
```

My gallery.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from gallery.views import GalleryDetailView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', GalleryDetailView.as_view(),
        name="galery_detail"),
]
```

Comment: Is gallery included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes @Sayse I can reach this url without reversing gallery_detail in homepage or anathor page

Comment: You've named your url `galery_detail`, single `l`. Should be `gallery_detail`.

Comment: @knbk Thank you very much :) I fixed the urls and it worked. Thank you again